# Unknown attribute error in create method of nested form with polymorphic object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to get a simple nested form working for a has_many belong_to polymorphic association. The form is rendering the fields but when it submits it giives an 'unknown attribute' error from the create method. Here is the relevant code:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, :as => :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images  
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.images.build
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

views/users/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>

    <%= form.fields_for :images, @user.images do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.file_field :images %>
    <% end %>

    <%= form.submit "Create user" %>
<% end %>
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true

  has_attached_file :image_resource
end
```

I am using the paperclip gem for the has_attached_file method in image.rb. The exact error is "unknown attribute: images"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops the only issue here is that I should have it be <%= builder.file_field :image_resource %>